# Components for Java application

Tags: java, architecture, spring-boot, derby, h2

I need to implement some kind of Java application that must be installed on client computers.

**Main requirements:**

1. This application must have internal data storage(RDBMS) and data
   must be durable.
2. HTTP server for RESTful Web Services(for incoming
   calls from outer world)
3. Easy installation process

Right now I'm thinking to implement this application on Spring Boot. It will allow us to simple run the application on embedded Tomcat with no need to install standalone Tomcat Server.

Also, for internal data storage(RDBMS) I plan to use embedded H2 or Derby databases. The main criterion - data must be durable between application restarts.

For RESTful Web Services I plan to user Spring RestController over Spring MVC.

What do you think about my choice? Will it work with these tools ? Thanks

Comment: The application must be installed (desktop app) or it must be web-app?

Comment: Web-app, backend with RESTfull WebServices and a simple web UI(some kind of dashboard)

Comment: And why do you want to install it on client computers, if it is a web app?

Comment: Opinion based **and** unclear. Which part of the software is in question here? Only the client?

Comment: This is a client/server application(all in one). It can receive calls from outer world via RESTfull WebServices and also It can call other applications via their RESTfull WebServices.

Comment: Yes it should work. How to use H2 or Derby to store the data in the file system needs to be checked - I 've no experience on it, but should be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice seems fine to me.

I have implemented an application with those components actually. As database I chose H2 because it has 
[features](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#comparison) which I needed compared to Derby, especially support for creating domains was important. Generally H2 seems to have more features than Derby.

As of data durability I can only say that so far I did not encounter any issues.

A RESTful API can easily be implemented with a `@RestController`.

You can run the Spring Boot application after login with the users credentials, and save the H2 database file somewhere in the users personal folders.

As a plus, running a local Java application like this, you can access the local filesystem (e.g. to store a PDF report directly in "My Documents".

**Edit:**

You can start the browser automatically when your App is ready, from the last initialized bean:

```
@Value("${server.port}")
private String          serverPort;

@Value("${server.context-path}")
private String          serverContextPath;

public void openAppInBrowser() {
    final Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
    if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
        logger.debug("Open Browser.");
        try {
            desktop.browse(new URI("http://localhost" +
                    (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(serverPort) ? ":" + serverPort : "") +
                    (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(serverContextPath) ? serverContextPath : "")));
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            logger.debug("Error opening Browser", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for additional info!